# Sinatra & Carrierwave: in `require': cannot load such file -- RMagick (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm trying to get a simple image uploader class working in Sinatra with Carrierwave. I've used almost identical code to this and specified the same lines in the Gemfile, but after running $bundle install and everything installing with no problem, I get a LoadError from the following code:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
gem 'rack'
gem 'thin'
gem "mongo_mapper"
gem 'bson_ext'

# Image uploading to S3
gem "fog", "~> 1.3.1"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2', :git=>'http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick.git', :require=>'RMagick'
```

CarrierWave config file:

```
# Configure Carrierwave Uploads to Amazon S3
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => '(never mind about this)',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => '(or this)'                        # required
    #:region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    #:host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    #:endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'penumbra-images'                     # required
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}

end
```

ImageUploader class definition:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  process :resize_to_fit => [1024, 1024]
  storage :fog
end
```

My results:

```
$ ruby app.rb
CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
/Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require': cannot load such file -- RMagick (LoadError)
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:67:in `rescue in block in <module:RMagick>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:64:in `block in <module:RMagick>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/concern.rb:121:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/concern.rb:121:in `append_features'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/Generator/init/uploader.rb:2:in `include'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/Generator/init/uploader.rb:2:in `<class:ImageUploader>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/Generator/init/uploader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require'
    from app.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Gemfile` you’ve specified the git version of RMagick. Bundler takes some special steps to add such libraries to Ruby’s load path, but they aren’t available when running without Bundler as they aren’t normal gems. When you run your app without Bunder with `ruby app.rb`, Bundler doesn’t get to add this project to the load path, so you get a LoadError.

To fix it, make sure you use Bundler to run your app:

```
$ bundle exec ruby app.rb
```

Alternatively you can set up Bundler in your code. Add

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

to the top of `app.rb` and Bundler will be setup every time you run.

Comment: Thank you very much, @matt! I had a different problem, but your answer has saved me a few hours.